# Document class CD to create beautiful CD cover

Tags: graphics, formatting, pdftex, covers

Does somebody know a document class like [`cd`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cd) to create cd covers where:

a) I can add a logo to the CD cover text and

b) the output is not a4
   (or so) but the exact size to fit a CD cover.

I tried to get a working CD cover with [this](http://vigna.di.unimi.it/cd/) template but do not manage to add a logo via `includegraphics` to the front page nor to get an output size fitting into a standard CD cover without having it to adjust with scissors after printing.

Comment: Have a look at [`DVD, CD, and MC Covers and Collections`](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/bytopic.html#cd).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a simlpe little example using [`cd-cover`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cd-cover):

```
\documentclass{cd-cover}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\CDbookletTopMargin=0pt
\CDbookletMargin=0pt
\begin{bookletsheets}
\vspace*{5mm}
\hspace{5mm}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE \LaTeX3}\par\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{expl3}
\end{center}
\end{bookletsheets}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Does this qualify as beautiful? I wouldn't know but you can beautify it as much as you want to.

Comment: I wonder how much effort would be needed to create a track listing.

Answer (score 13):

It is not a `documentsclass`, but also very viable: the `papercdcase` package. It's beautiful because it's foldable ;)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{papercdcase}

\setcdbackmatter{%
  \centering
  \huge\bfseries\LaTeX3\par
  \includegraphics[scale=.5]{expl3.png}
}

\begin{document}
\centering\papercdcase*
\end{document}
```

[image: output]