# CD (compact disk) label class/template?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, formatting, templates

I've [found this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/256364/98645) to create a CD cover and [this for a paper-only version even](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/papercdcase).

However, I want to create a simple CD *label*, i.e. one you can print *on* a CD directly.
Just these default 650 MB CD's.

From it's style, it may be like a simple title page, so auhor, title, date. That's it.

Basically, this just means two circles and some text fields, I guess.

Are there any templates actually? This idea cannot be new.

I've also tried it by myself, but I did not really got far and have no experience in tikz usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[papersize={13cm, 13cm}, margin=0pt, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \vspace{0.5cm} % tried to center the result, but this failed :(
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (6,6) circle (6cm); % maybe 6.1 for some padding for print
        \draw (6,6) circle (0.685cm); % don't know if that is the right size
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\cdrdisk` or some others similar commands of the `simplecd` package.  If you have a distro installed, run `texdoc simplecd` for more information, or search it in CTAN. Example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simplecd,xcolor,parskip}
\begin{document}
\color{gray!50}
\cdrdisk{\color{blue}\Huge 
Huge Title \par\medskip\large 
The author\par\normalsize
\today    
\vspace{2cm}\par\Large\quad 
Left text     \hfill  
Right text  \vspace{2cm}\quad{}\par
Lower text\par 
Lower text\par 
Lower text}
\end{document}
```